# iOS Mapbox: Map offline + Price

Tags: ios, dictionary, mapbox, offline

My newest Swift app has Offline map feature. I am using Mapbox to support my app. However, the area I want to download limited with 6000 tiles. I couldn't download full map (In my case, it's New York City map). Somebody, who knew about it, please tell me some specify info about price levels. I couldn't find helpful things on their support page: https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/

I already sent a support ticket and a email to Mapbox Sales Deputy, but I didn't get any reply until now.

Answer (score 3):

I also asked Mapbox about this recently.  Their reply (in part) was:

> Increasing the tile limit per end user mobile device is a feature only of our Enterprise plans

Comment: So I need to pay some money. ^^. Thanks for your information.

Comment: How much money did it cost you?

Comment: I have not paid for it, as it was way too high for my budget.  They quoted $25,000 per year for the Enterprise plan.  Hopefully the decide to provide some more reasonable options for increasing the tile limit.